# How to send html test report generated by Minitest-reporters

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am using [Minitest-reporters](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters) with MiniTest to generate an HTML test report after each test run. How to email this generated test file?

I tried doing it in the `teardown` method of the test class. But `teardown` function is executed for each test function and not after the whole test run.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, you could define new rake tasks an fit them together with existing tasks. See your `Rakefile`. So you may define a new task which will send the file and then you let it run after `rake test` has been run.

```
Rake::TestTask.new("test:send_report") do |t|
  t.verbose = true

  # do here what is to do
end

Rake::Task["test"].enhance do
  Rake::Task["test:send_report"].invoke
end
```

This will cause 'test:send_report' to be invoked after 'test'.

My ruby times are years ago, I don't remember all details exactly and I didn't define rake tasks every day. You need a little investigation on rake tasks, but may be it could be a solution strategy for you.